# Is it safe to use the std::string::c_str() of a temporary string?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer, stdstring, temporary-objects

Is the following C++ code well-formed?

```
void consumer(char const* p)
{
  std::printf("%s", p);
}

std::string random_string_generator();

consumer(random_string_generator().c_str());
```

The problem I have with it is, that after creating the temporary `std::string` object and taking the `c_str()` pointer, nothing prevents the `std::string` object from getting destroyed, unless I'm wrong.

Is this code well-formed according to the standard? It does work, when I test with g++.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The pointer returned by `std::string::c_str()` points to memory 
maintained by the string object.  It remains valid until a non-const
function is called on the string object, or the string object is
destructed.  The string object you're concerned about is a temporary.
It will be destructed at the end of the full expression, not before and
not after.  In your case, the end of the full expression is after the
call to `consumer`, so your code is safe.  It wouldn't be if `consumer`
saved the pointer somewhere, with the idea of using it later.

The lifetime of temporaries has been strictly defined since C++98.
Before that, it varied, depending on the compiler, and the code you've
written wouldn't have worked with g++ (pre 1995, roughly—g++
changed this almost immediately when the standards committee voted it).
(There wasn't an `std::string` then either, but the same issues affect
any user written string class.)

Comment: what if one used the `c_str()` `const char*` in a subsequent statement (still inside the function, but outside the first statement)? Would this bring us a dangling pointer?

Comment: I answer myself... In that case it would be invalid:
_§ 12.2 ... Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception._

Comment: std::string temp = random_string_generator().c_str();

Is this correct to assume temp would be correct?
since the life time of the string returned from random_string_generator() will be till the end of expression?

Comment: @AyushPant, yes. The `const char*` is valid when initializing `temp` which copies the characters. But why not just move the string returned by the function?

Answer (score 26):

The temporary `std::string`'s lifetime extends just beyond the point where `consumer` returns, so it is safe to use anything on that string *directly from within `consumer`*. What is *not* OK is to store the value that `c_str` returns and try to use it later (the temporary will have been destroyed, and we can only guess what you will find at the other end of the pointer).

Comment: can you provide a hint as regards the C++03 or the C++11 standard please?

Comment: The lifetime of a temporary is defined in §12.2.  (Section 12 is
entitled "Special member functions", which isn't exactly where you'd
expect to look for lifetime of temporaries, but that's where it is.)

Comment: @user1095108 and lifetime of function arguments can be obtained from §3.2.2 and §3.7.2 in the c++03 standard.

Answer (score 6):

The temporary returned by the function random_string_generator() can be used in consumer() function safely.