# printf() confusion - printing (null) when trying to print string and printing correct value when printing buffer

Tags: c++, string, null, printf

see simplified code - I'm confused...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>      
#include <cstdlib>  // includes the standard library and overarchs over stdlib.h

using namespace std;  
void main()
{
    char buffer[10];
    string theString;
    int i = 997799; //(simplified)
    itoa(i,buffer,10);                      
    theString = buffer;             

    printf("\n string is: %s of length %d \n", theString, theString.length());
    printf("\n buffer is: %s of length %d \n", buffer, theString.length());
    return;
}
```

The Output I get is unexpected:

```
string is: (null) of length 926366009
buffer is: 997799 of length 6
```

(1) why is the string printing as null?

(2) why is theString.length() not printing properly in the first printf() but is right in the 2nd?

(3) if I set breakpoints in visual studio 'buffer' appears as "997799" while 'theString' appears as {"997799"} - something weird going on here?

Thanks folks!
*Edit* I greatly appreciate the level of detail of the provided answers - they all added clarity and helped me go beyond my issue - many thanks for the time you spent helping out :)

Comment: `void main` is not legal. Use `int main`. `itoa` isn't a standard function. And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `%s` specifier with `printf()` you promise to pass a `char const*` as the corresponding argument. Passing anything except a `char const*` or something which decays into a `char const*` is undefined behavior. Certainly, passing a C++ object will have undefined behavior.

The proper way to pass a `std::string` to `printf()` is to use the `%s` format specifier and use the `c_str()` member, e.g.:

```
printf("string=%s\n", s.c_str());
```

You are using `%d` as a format specifier for `std::string::size_type`. That will *probably* work but it isn't guaranteed to work! Although `std::string::size_type` is guaranteed to be `std::size_t`, this type may be `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`, or even some non-standard built-in integral type! The proper way to spell the format specifier for `std::size_t` is `%zu` (and certainly not `%ul` as in another post: it was probably meant to be `%lu` which is, however, still wrong:

```
printf("string.size()=%zu\n", s.size());
```

Since you are using C++, you are probably better off having the compiler figure out what formatting to call:

```
std::cout << "\n string is: " << theString << " of length " << theString.length() << " \n";
std::cout << "\n buffer is: " << buffer << " of length " << theString.length() << " \n";
```

Answer (score 3):

The program has undefined behaviour because function printf is unable to output objects of type std::string. When format symbol %s is used the function supposes that the corresponding argument is a pointer of a string literal. So the function tries to output the object of type std::string as a string literal.
To use correctly function printf with objects of type std::string you should convert them to strings using member function c_str() or data() (for C++ 2011). For example

```
printf("\n string is: %s of length %ul \n", theString.c_str(), theString.length());
```

Comment: Not that `%ul` is _not_ a format specifier for `unsigned long` although it is the literal suffix: `%ul` is `%u` for an `unsigned int` followed by an `l` character. You probably meant to write `%lu` which is, however, still wrong: the correct format specifier for `std::size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl, I think you are wrong. From the C Standard l (ell) Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long int or unsigned long int...

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl Or did you mean that should be used %lu? As for size_t then thanks. I could not remember the specifier at that moment when I was writing the post.

Comment: `size_t`'s size is _not_ specified and it isn't guaranteed that it is of type `unsigned long`. For `size_t` the proper length modifier is `z` (see 7.21.6.1 paragraph 7, sixth item: "`z` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `size_t` or the corresponding signed integer type argument; ..."). ... and the length modifier precedes the conversion specifier, i.e., `%zu` for `size_t` and `%lu` for `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer pointed out, the reason for the `(null)` value is because the (formal) [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) `%s` expects a `const char*` for its input, a `std::string` is *not* a `const char*` and results in undefined behavior... The reason for the random number when you do your first `theString.length()` has to do with your compiler.

On OpenBSD 5.1 with g++ 4.2.1, when I compile the code I get numerous warnings; one in particular is use of `itoa`, I had to change to `sprintf`, I also get the following warning about `%s` with `printf` on a `std::string`: `warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type 'struct std::string' through '...'; call will abort at runtime`.

When I run the compiled code it aborts and core dumps at the first `printf` because of the call to `%s` on a `std::string` 'object' (which is the 'correct' behavior though technically still 'undefined behavior')

However, when I compile the above code (without edits) on an MS compiler, I actually get the following output:

```
string is: 997799 of length 6
buffer is: 997799 of length 6
```

Which is still 'undefined' but the 'expected' results.

So apparently the MS compiler recognizes the `std::string` on a `printf` and 'changes' it to a `string.c_str()` call OR the `printf` in the MS C/C++ library accepts a `std::string` and calls the `.c_str()` for you.

So to be 100% 'compatible' and C++ 'compliant' consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::stringstream theString;
    int i = 997799; //(simplified)
    theString << i;

    std::cout << "string is: " << theString.str() << " of length " << theString.str().length() << std::endl;
    // printf("string is: %s of length %d \n", theString.str().c_str(), theString.str().length());
    return 0;
}
```

It's usually not good practice to mix C++ and C calls/styles, but IMHO I use `printf` a lot for it's 'convenience' but usually take it out or use some `#defines` for debug build use only.

I hope that can help answer the 'why for #2'

Answer (score 0):

My compiler (clang on os x) reports the following errors:

```
c++     foo.cc   -o foo
foo.cc:6:1: error: 'main' must return 'int'
void main()
^~~~
int
foo.cc:11:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'itoa'
    itoa(i,buffer,10);                      
    ^
foo.cc:14:48: error: cannot pass non-POD object of type 'string' (aka
      'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to variadic
      function; expected type from format string was 'char *'
      [-Wnon-pod-varargs]
    printf("\n string is: %s of length %d \n", theString, theString.length());
                          ~~                   ^~~~~~~~~
foo.cc:14:48: note: did you mean to call the c_str() method?
    printf("\n string is: %s of length %d \n", theString, theString.length());
                                               ^
                                                        .c_str()
foo.cc:14:59: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wformat]
    printf("\n string is: %s of length %d \n", theString, theString.length());
                                       ~~                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                       %lu
foo.cc:15:56: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wformat]
    printf("\n buffer is: %s of length %d \n", buffer, theString.length());
                                       ~~              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                       %lu
```

Let's fix them:

1. `void main() { ... }` should be `int main() { ... }`.
2. `itoa()` is not standard in C++. There is [`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) though, so let's use that instead. We could also use [`std::snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) if we are writing to a character array, and not a `std::string`.
3. If we're going to use `printf()` with a `std::string`, we will need to use the `std::string::c_str()` method to return a character array and print that instead. printf itself doesn't understand C++ objects. (We could also use cout, which does understand c++ objects).

These changes cause the code to look like:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>      
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char buffer[10];
    string theString;
    int i = 997799; //(simplified)

    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", i);
    theString = buffer;

    printf("string is: %s of length %lu\n", theString.c_str(), theString.length());
    printf("buffer is: %s of length %lu\n", buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```

And this code outputs:

```
[4:46pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./foo
string is: 997799 of length 6
buffer is: 997799 of length 6
```

Comment: As stated before, `%lu` is the wrong format specifier: there is no guarantee that `std::size_t` is a `typedef` for `unsigned long`. The correct format specifier is `%zu`. Conveniently, that clearly states that C's format specifiers are really hard to use, making it is clear that using IOStreams is safer.