# Non-POD object error

Tags: c++

So, I've read a lot online for this error, but for some reason, I'm still getting it even after I have tried the suggested things.  If anyone could help me understand this and point out what's wrong, that would be awesome.

```
char * s = strtok(text, ",");
string name = s;
printf("%s", name);
```

Comment: `printf()` takes a `char *` for `%s`, not a `std::string`. You can't just ignore that requirement. `printf("%s", name.c_str());` might work for you.

Comment: Do you need to even be using `printf`? You should be using streams ie. `std::cout << name << std::endl`.

Comment: Just putting it out there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring

Comment: I would also suggest tokenising your string differently, again if you are actually using c++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example code the error you get is saying something like you cannot pass a non-POD object to an ellipses. This is because you are trying to pass a non-POD type to a variadic function, one that takes a variable number of arguments. In this case by calling `printf` which is declared something like the below

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

The ellipsis used as the last parameter allows you to pass 0 or more additional arguments to the function as you are doing in your code. The C++ standard **does** allow you to pass a non-POD type but compilers are not **required** to support it. This is covered in part by 5.2.2/7 of the standard.

> Passing a potentially-evaluated argument of class type having a non-trivial copy constructor, a non-trivial move contructor, or a non-trivial destructor, with no corresponding parameter, is conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics.

This means it is up to each compiler maker to decide **if** they want to support it **and** how it will behave. Apparently your compiler does not support this and even if it did I wouldn't recommend using it.