# I can't figure out std::string substr

Tags: c++, string

my font filename extractor is not working...
filename_: `".\\Source\\AlexBrush-Regular.ttf"`
and I'm using

```
sprintf(buffer, "\nFont Name:%s \nNumber of errors: %d\nAscent %d High +%d Descent -%d Low -%d!", 
                font->filename_.substr( font->filename_.find_last_of('\\'), font->filename_.length() ), hitcount, Ascent, Descent, High, Low);
```

my ouput looks like
buffer  0x008aecbc `"\nFont Name:ÀëŠ \nNumber of errors: 12688232\nAscent -858993460 High +-858993460 Descent --858993460 Low -22!"`

Comment: You are trying to use `sprintf` with a `std::string`.

Comment: `sprintf` supports only C types. Here's a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring).

Comment: I added c_str() to the end, thank you for the fix!

Comment: @NarayanaJamesEmery, Consider a `std::ostringstream`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `basename(font->filename_.c_str())` which does exactly what you want to do and is platform-independent.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem with a little example :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filename(".\\Source\\AlexBrush-Regular.ttf");

    cout << filename.substr(filename.find_last_of('\\') + 1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is :
**AlexBrush-Regular.ttf**

First, I add "1" to the first parameter, because the function *find_last_of()* will search the position of the last character and I don't think you want to include it in your output.
Secondly, I erase the second argument, because the default value is string::npos and it indicates all characters until the end of the string.

If you have always your problem, please be more specific to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a better idea to solve this using C++ facilities (i.e. `stringstream`) rather than C facilities, considering you are using a `std::string`. In that case, please see [this snippet here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9rJB9RcweNCGZbXN) for how you might do that.

If you insist on using `sprintf`, then you will have to get the underlying `c-string`, which you can call like:

```
const std::string mystr("foo");
const char *mycstr(mystr.c_str());
```