# Error while taking array of strings as input

Tags: c++, arrays, string, scanf

I am trying to take array of string as a input but its giving run time error

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdio>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string str[500];
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%s",&str[i]); \\works fine with cin but gives error using scanf
        return 0;
    }
```

> > Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 10 second(s))
> >
> > > **works fine with `cin` but give error if i use `scanf`**
> >
> > Can some one tell me *why its giving such error*
> >
> > > *what does that error mean
> > >       and why doesn't it gives error while using `cin`*
>
> I am using code blocks 13.12

Comment: [Same reason as `printf`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring/10865967#10865967)

Comment: and whats the reason??

Comment: `scanf` is a C function, and has no idea about C++ classes and objects like, for example, `std::string`.

Comment: @rajnish, > [`scanf`] has no option for std::string, only a C-style string. Using something else in place of what it expects definitely won't give you the results you want. It's actually undefined behaviour, so anything at all could happen.

Comment: @chris can u please elaborate it a bit more, i got that its like undefined for C-style string but how does that exactly work, i mean to say i have included cstdio libraries so compiler would get its reference from there, so i am a bit confused how it works in the background, like y its undefined?

Comment: @rajnish, `scanf` supports a limited set of types. `std::string` is obviously not on that list because `std::string` is a C++ type and `scanf` is a C function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf()` is meant to be used with C-style strings(aka `char *` or `char[]`), it should be

```
char myString[101];
char* myOtherString = (char*)malloc(101);
scanf("%100s", myString);
scanf("%100s", myOtherString);
free(myOtherString);
```

no reason to use this over `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is a C++ type, you should use C++ I/Os thus `cin` and `cout`. If you really want to use C I/Os you can access `c_str` method to get the C `char *` behind the `string`.

Comment: Not `c_str()` because that gives a `const char *`. You need to resize it so that it's big enough to hold the string without modifying the null character at the end and then use something like `&str[i][0]`. This is only guaranteed to work in C++11, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using C++ to take advantage of cin 
The  header file avoids the use of non null pointers and char arrays

cin>> has operator overload and users the modern string class