# Using printf to print string value

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

In C# I can easily enumerate through an array of strings. However, why doesn't the code below work in C++?

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string hi[] = { "hi", "cool", "what" };

    for (string s : hi)
    {
        printf("%s \n", s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I tried using this instead, but it doesn't work either:

```
printf(s);
```

Oddly enough, an array on integers does work, but using `%d`. And yes, I do have `#include <string>`.

Error information provided by @chris (generated by the [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) compiler):

> main.cpp:12:25: error: cannot pass non-trivial object of type 'string' (aka `'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >'`) to variadic function; expected type from format string was 'char *' [-Wnon-pod-varargs]
>
> ```
>   printf("%s \n", s);
>            ~~      ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:12:25: note: did you mean to call the c_str() method?
>
> ```
>   printf("%s \n", s);
>                    ^
>                     .c_str()
> ```

Comment: Filling in a couple missing things above this, Clang gives a [perfectly clear error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3878b5362323ab75). This might [help to explain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring/10865967#10865967), though.

Comment: @chris - I've inlined error message you've provided to make question look reasonable.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I saw. It certainly helps to have an error, but it's worth noting that the one the OP is getting is probably not half as straightforward as that on what to do about it.

Comment: Hmmm... now since I've changed the title there is very good duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring

Comment: @chris probably, since OP did not provide any information what they use to compile it is hard to say... Also "variadic function" may confuse newcomer completely from even reading past first line anyway :)

Comment: Just a few notes to your code example: In your for loop `s` is actually copied, which you might not expect when coming from C#, in case you just want to print them you definitely want to use `for(const string & s: hi)`. Also you might want to use C++ containers instead of C arrays and obviously `std::cout` instead of `printf`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I added a footnote to explain things for the curious.

Comment: @hynner  Good catch! I edited my answer to use a const reference instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::cout` instead of `printf`.
The problem is that you are passing a `std::string` to `printf`, when you actually need a `const char*`. Using `std::string::c_str` solves this. But its better to not use `printf` in the first place.

[Live working example](http://ideone.com/AtiraP)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string hi[] = { "hi", "cool", "what" };

    for (const std::string& s : hi) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was told by my instructor to avoid using `cout`. Is there not a way to accomplish this using `printf`?

Comment: @Vippy There is, as the other answers as well as this one mention: Using `s.c_str()` instead of just `s` in the call to `printf`. Which I do not recommend because of type safety. Google it if you want to learn the details.

Comment: @Vippy, I won't jump and say it's bad advice, but your instructor should certainly be able to back that up with solid reasons instead of it being a "because I say so" rule. Personally, if advising to use `printf`, might as well use a small library that is type safe and extensible (i.e., would work with types like `std::string` and your own types).

Comment: In a nutshell, he gave 2 main reasons he doesn't like it: First if I remember correctly, he said something about `cout` being a class that doesn't behave like a class because it uses some trickery with shift left bitwise operator. And second, he compiled 3 programs using `puts()`, `printf()` and `cout`. `puts()` and `printf()` were roughly the same size, however `cout` was twice the size.

Comment: @Vippy, I can understand not liking the shift operators being overloaded, and many people agree it was a bad design choice. However, if the reason for disliking it is that it is unexpected, this usage is so popular now that the bit shift operators have have become known as input and output operators in some textbooks. As for the extra code size, I haven't tested, but assuming it's true, I would understand if a bit of executable size were a concern. In a teaching environment, it probably makes no difference, but it definitely can elsewhere.

Comment: @Vippy Unless you are programming for embedded systems, you don´t need to be concerned with executable sizes. In that case, using a `std::string` is probably a bad idea aswell, so there´s that ;)  `std::cout` is not a class but an object, and it behaves like one. Your instructor should probably brush up on modern c++ programming :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) property of each string (it returns `char*` pointer that [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) knows how to print correctly):

```
for (string s : hi)
{
    printf("%s \n", s.c_str());
}
```

Just take into account that `printf` is part of older [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) input-output facilities. While they will work in most cases when used correctly, it is better at least not to mix them with C++ streams (std::cin and [std::cout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/)), and even much better is to use more [advanced facilities](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) of newer `<iostream>` classes:

```
for (std::string s : hi)
{
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `printf` (which is a native C function) expects to get a C-string (i.e., `char*` which is a sequence of characters terminated by '\0') rather than an object of type `string` which is a C++ type.

However, you can simply convert from `string` to a C-string by using the `c_str()` method on the string, i.e., change your original call to `printf` to `printf("%s \n", s.c_str());`.

Alternatively, you can use the C++ standard way for printing to the console using `std::cout` (some examples were provided in the other answers).