# c++ how can I display the string attribute of an element at a particular position in a vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector, std

I am trying to print the value of a C++ variable in the console for debugging purposes. The line that I am using to try and do this is:

```
    printf("\n Value of lTempCoord in CSARCreepingLineItem::SteerStep(...): %s", rm_WPSequence[m_SAR_OrdinalNumber].m_FixName);
```

But the output that this line generates is unreadable. I am wondering if this is because I am trying to display it using a 'string' character `%s` but then passing something other than a simple string/ character array to it?

Breaking down the variable that I am passing to the `printf()`:

`rm_WPSequence` is a Vector, defined with:

```
vector< CUserWaypointListElement > rm_WPSequence;
```

`m_SAR_OrdinalNumber` is an int, and

`m_FixName` is a string, defined inside the `CUserWaypoingListElement` class with:

```
std::string m_FixName;
```

The output generated by the line is a few 'special' characters (not ones that you can see on the keyboard).

What am I doing wrong here? Is the output unreadable because I'm not accessing the member of the `Vector` correctly, or because the `string` is defined as part of the `std` library? Or is it something else completely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ printf with std::string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring)

Comment: Also use std::ostringstream or std::wostringstream instead of printf.  For std::string, the C pointer is .c_str().  For stream it's .str().c_str().

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
std::cout << rm_WPSequence[m_SAR_OrdinalNumber].m_FixName  << std::endl;
```

`printf` is basically a `C` function, you should use `c++` mechanism in your `c++` programs ;). If you really want to use `printf()`, transform your `std::string` in `char *` by using the `std::string.c_str()` method