# Why can't I pass string* instead of string[] as argument?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int main(int args, char* argv[]) {
    string* list;
    listDevices(list);
    printf("device 0: %s\n", list[0]); // prints some junks
}

void listDevices(string* list) {
    list = new string[1];
    list[0] = "abc";
    printf("device 0: %s\n", list[0]); //prints "abc"
}
```

In the above code, `list` array is initialized and assigned some values in the `listDevices` method, but when I print it outside the function, some junks would be printed.

Why does it work correctly if I send `string list[1]` as input to the above method but not when sending `string* list` (although both are pointers)?

Comment: `void listDevices(string*& list)`

Comment: `string list[1]` is an array, not a pointer. In "the above code", `list` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: This is a very messy code. At least use `delete` when you use `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` is a variable of type `pointer-to-string`, which you pass by value. Changing `list` itself inside the method won't carry the changes outside the scope of the method.

You want to pass it by reference:

```
void listDevices(string*& list)
```

Answer (score 3):

You only change a local copy of the pointer in `listDevices`. The pointer in `main` remains unchanged. You probably want to return a pointer to the new list:

```
string *listDevices() {
    string *list = new string[1];
    list[0] = "abc";
    printf("device 0: %s\n", list[0]); //prints "abc"
    return list;
}

int main(int args, char* argv[]) {
    string *list = listDevices();
    printf("device 0: %s\n", list[0]); // Will now work
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass the pointer by reference, but I prefer the return method for stylistic reasons.

---

By the way, you probably do not need to use a pointer and `printf` in the first place. Most likely, your code should look somewhat like this:

```
std::string listDevices () {
    std::string ret = "abc";
    std::cout << ret << "\n";
    return ret;
}

int main () {
    std::string str = listDevices();
    std::cout << ret << "\n";
}
```

Comment: can not pass the argument here:  string *list = listDevices(list);

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `list` as reference to function as:

```
void listDevices(string* &list) {
    list = new string[3];
    list[0] = "abc";
    printf("device 0: %s\n", list[0].c_str()); //prints "abc"
}

int main(int args, char* argv[]) {
    string* list=nullptr;
    listDevices(list);
    printf("device 0: %s\n", list[0].c_str()); //now prints "abc"
    // Don't forget to do `delete[] list` at the end !
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** As you tag `c++` in your question, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring) which indicate to using `.c_str()` while printing a `std::string` with `printf`.

**caution:** Don't forget to do `delete[] list` at the end !