# How to convert a char[] to a std::string

Tags: c++

I´m trying to convert a char[] into a std::string. Everywhere I looked, I found the same answer, that string has a constructor doing this exact thing.
The trouble is, it doesn´t work for me.

Here is my code:

```
std::string getKey(double xTop,double yTop,double zTop,double xBottom,double yBottom,double zBottom,double zGridPoint)
{
      std::string outfile = correctPath(getCurrentDirectory().toStdString()) + "keys.txt";
      FILE *f;
      f= fopen(outfile.c_str(),"a");
      char buffer[100];
      double s;

      if((zBottom-zTop) ==0)
      {
            sprintf(buffer,"%e %e %e", xTop, yTop, zTop); 
      }else
      {
            s=(zGridPoint - zTop) / (zBottom - zTop);
            sprintf(buffer,"%e %e %e",xTop+ s*(xBottom - xTop), yTop+ s*(yBottom - yTop), zGridPoint);

      }

      std::string ret (buffer);
      fprintf(f,"buffer: %s ; ret: %s\n",buffer,ret);
      fclose(f);
      return ret;
}
```

The fprintf is to check if my string is correct, which isn´t the case.
buffer gets printed correctly, but ret gives me some strange signs I can neither read nor reproduce here.

Does anyone see a problem with my code?

Thanks

Comment: try fprintf(f,"buffer: %s ; ret: %s\n",&buffer,ret);

Comment: `%s` cannot be used with `std::string`. try `fprintf(...,ret.c_str());`

Comment: @hanshenrik No, that’s not correct.

Comment: Don't use old C-style formatting functions for C++ objects, it simply will not work. The compiler should have shouted at you for that. Use C++ streams instead.

Comment: sorry, didn´t work. The & changed nothing at all.
I also tried fprintf(f,"buffer: %s ; ret: %s\n",&buffer,&ret);

Comment: ret.c_str() didn´t work either.

Comment: Please provide the whole attempt, because `fprintf(f, "buffer: %s ; ret: %s\n", buffer, ret.c_str());` should have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ret` isn't a `char*`. However, `printf`'s `%s` specifier requires a `char*` (i.e., a C-style string).

You can either use `printf` with `ret.c_str()` (which makes your string unnecessary, because you convert it right back to a char array) or C++ output facilities:

```
fprintf(f, "buffer: %s ; ret: %s\n", buffer, ret.c_str());

std::ofstream f(outfile);
f << ret << std::endl;
f.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a string object into printf using %s.

You need to pass `ret.c_str()` as a parameter, or better yet, use `cout`.

Read more here: [C++ printf with std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring)