# Need help using C++ Class Inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am trying to run the following C++ code to understand class inheritance using MS Visual Studio 15. After I build and run the code, I get a message saying MS VS has stopped working. I'd really appreciate if someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

// BASE CLASS
class Animal {
private:
    string _name;
    string _type;
    string _sound;
    Animal() {};     
protected: 
    Animal(const string &n, const string &t, const string &s) :_name(n), _type(t), _sound(s) {};    
public: 
    void speak() const;     
};

void Animal::speak() const {
    printf("%s, the %s says %s.\n", _name, _type, _sound);
}

// DERIVED CLASSES 
class Dog :public Animal { 
private:
    int walked;
public:
    Dog(const string &n) :Animal(n, "dog", "woof"), walked(0) {};
    int walk() { return ++walked; }
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {    
    Dog d("Jimmy"); 
    d.speak();          
    printf("The dog has been walked %d time(s) today.\n", d.walk());        
    return 0;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: `someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong` You have got a diamond problem in your VS2015

Comment: Obey warnings [when compiling](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b01383841d47037d)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%s, the %s says %s.\n", _name, _type, _sound);
```

You cannot use `std::string` with `printf()` that way.

Use

```
printf("%s, the %s says %s.\n", _name.c_str(), _type.c_str(), _sound.c_str());
```

instead.

---

I'd rather recommend to use `std::cout` to get everything seamlessly working in c++.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the speak method tries to use printf in order to print a string object.

The [printf function is not suitable for printing std::string objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring). It does works on char arrays, which are used for representing strings in the C language.
If you want to use printf anyway, you'll need convert your strings into char arrays. This can be done as follows:

```
printf("%s, the %s says %s.\n", _name.c_str(), _type.c_str(), _sound.c_str());
```

A more elegant solution, will be to print the data in the "C++" way, by using std::cout:

```
//include declaration at the top of the document
#include <iostream>
...
//outputs the result
cout <<_name + ", the " + _type + " says " + _sound << "." << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) with `%s` expects a [c-style null-terminated byte string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte), not `std::string`, they're not the same thing. So `printf("%s, the %s says %s.\n", _name, _type, _sound);` won't work, it shouldn't compile.

You can use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str), which will return a `const char*`. Such as

```
printf("%s, the %s says %s.\n", _name.c_str(), _type.c_str(), _sound.c_str());
```

Or use `std::cout` with `std::string` like:

```
cout << _name << ", the " << _type << " says " << _sound << ".\n";
```