# Access pointer class members (c++)

Tags: c++

I have the TestObject class:

```
public:
    TestObject() {}
    std::string name;
```

In main function I do this

```
TestObject *to = new TestObject();
std::string t = "r";
to->name = t;
printf("%s",t);
```

I need to save simple string in name file on class object, but I'm doing with the wrong way. What is the solution?

Comment: These are basics covered in any C++ book - I don't think this question is appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but the *real* solution here is to do some more learning *first*. You see, in contrast to popular believe, this site is **not** "programming school, where people explain you the super basics" for free. Sometimes we do, but in any case: it is far more effective for you to, well, do some more research *yourself*.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Strings with printf
[C++ printf with std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring)

Here is a working code

```
class TestObject
{
public:
    TestObject()
    {}
    std::string name;
};
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    TestObject * to = new TestObject();
    std::string t = "r";
    to -> name = t;
    std::cout << t; // or printf("%s",t.c_str());
    delete to;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I add the c_str() and it is work. I will seach now the 'paper' of this functions. thanks ;)