# Print vector <string> m[][] in C++

Tags: c++

I need to print the strings from this 3d matrix using an iterator.

This is the declaration

`vector <string> transicoes[estados.size()][alfabeto.size()];`

I tried printing like this

`printf("%s", transicoes[i][j][k]);`

but I get this error message:

`cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type`

How can I do this?

EDIT: changed to cout and it works now, thanks

Comment: Use `iostream` instead.

Comment: stop using `printf` and use `std::cout`.

Comment: `printf` is a C function, and since C doesn't have `string`s, `printf`doesn't know a `string` from a hole in the ground. Because `printf` uses a variable argument list, the compiler may not even give you a warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ printf with std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/c-printf-with-stdstring)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that C functions are not compatible with C++ structures. Try doing this instead:

```
printf("%s", transicoes[i][j][k].c_str());
```

The `c_str()` call returns a const `char*` to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string, which is a C-like string.

But if you are working with C++, you should use the stream operators `<<` and `>>`. The code would then loop like this:

```
std::cout << transicoes[i][j][k] << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , I had to switch to from C to C++ without almost any knowledge of C++ to deal with a lot of dynamic sized vectors. So yeah...