# Plus operator on strings in c++

Tags: c++, string

Can you explain me the Exercise 1-2 from accelerated c++?

```
int main()
{
    const std::string exclam = "!";
    const std::string message = "Hello" + ", world" + exclam;
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

Why is this not correct? 
Changing the variable with "Hello" works fine.

Is it because of the fact that the operator + is right-associative?

Comment: No, because it's left-associative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of `operator+` is left-to-right. Then `"Hello" + ", world" + exclam` is interpreted as `("Hello" + ", world") + exclam` while `"Hello" + ", world"` is invalid. `"Hello"` and `", world"` are `const char[]`s and could decay to pointer as `const char*` which can't be added.

Using `std::string` instead of c-style string, or changing the code to `"Hello" + (", world" + exclam)` works because there's [`operator+` for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) which could accept two `std::string`s or a `std::string` and a c-style string (as either the 1st or 2nd operand), and it returns `std::string` which could be added further.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the explanation of [@songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61727311/5203275), you can do this either by using the `+` operator of `std::string`:

```
const std::string left  = "Hello ";
const std::string right = "World";
const std::string point = "!";
std::cout << left + right + point << std::endl;
```

or by manipulating the output directly with `std::cout`:

```
const std::string left  = "Hello";
const std::string right = "World";
const std::string point = "!";
std::cout << left << " " << right << point << std::endl;
```

Or by using the `printf` function *(don't forget to `#include <stdio.h>`)*:

```
const std::string left  = "Hello";
const std::string right = "World";
const std::string point = "!";
printf("%s %s%s\n", left.c_str(), right.c_str(), point.c_str());
```

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/printf-with-stdstring) if you want to know what the `c_str()` is about.