# can i use printf to print element of c++ array of strings

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
        (i >= 1 && i <= 9) ? printf("%d\n", s[i - 1]) : i % 2 ? printf("odd\n") : printf("even\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am using a ternary operator to print integer into word if it lies between 1 to 9 otherwise printing whether it's even or odd. I am not able to use cout in ternary operator and if I used printf then it's printing a character. can anybody tell me how to do that. I wanted to do the entire stuff in one line, is it possible?

Comment: `s[i - 1]` is a `string`, so you can't print it with `printf` and `%d`. If you *must* use `printf` then try `printf("%s\n", s[i - 1].c_str())` instead. But you should better use `cout` and readable code rather that cryptic one-liners.

Comment: use `%s` to format a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [printf with std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/printf-with-stdstring)

Comment: Interesting that you can't use `cout`. Seems to work fine over here: https://ideone.com/RCIbSl

Comment: You've already included `<iostream>` (but not `<cstdio>` that is needed for `std::printf`) so _why_ use `printf` instead of `std::cout` ?

Comment: Re: "I am using a ternary operator" -- why? An ordinary `if ... else if ...` ladder would be much clearer. A ternary **operator** is intended to compute a value; the code here doesn't use that value, so there's no need for this obfuscation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cout`. Like so:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::string s[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
        std::cout << ((i >= 1 && i <= 9) ? s[i-1]: (i % 2) ? "odd": "even") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`%d` prints decimal numers to the console. To print strings, you need the `%s` token and make sure that you get the `const char*` of it using `s[i - 1].c_str()`.