# Problem in comparing two strings with c++

Tags: c++

I have been learning c++ recently and that's a simple calculator app I have made, the problem comes when I receive an operator and I start to validate that it's one of (+, -, *,). but it doesn't seem to work

```
    if(op != "+" || op != "*" || op != "/" || op != "-"){
      std::cerr << "Error Unsupported Operator";
      return 0;
    };
```

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// km = 1.6 * miles
// Enter miles: 5

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::string num1, num2, op;
    double dNum1, dNum2;
    std::cout << "Enter first num: ";
    getline(std::cin, num1);
    std::cout << "Enter Operator: ";
    getline(std::cin, op);  
    if(op != "+" || op != "*" || op != "/" || op != "-"){
      std::cerr << "Error Unsupported Operator";
      return 0;
    };
    std::cout << "Enter second num: ";
    getline(std::cin, num2);
    dNum1 = std::stod(num1);   
    dNum2 = std::stod(num2);

    double result;
    
    if      (op == "+") result = dNum1 + dNum2;
    else if (op == "-") result = dNum1 - dNum2;
    else if (op == "*") result =  dNum1 * dNum2;  
    else if (op == "/") result =   dNum1 / dNum2;  

    // std::cout << dNum1 << " " << op << " " << dNum2 << " = " << result << "\n";
    printf("%.1f %s %.1f = %.1f", dNum1 , op ,dNum2, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've never seen `!==` before.  What do you suppose it does?

Comment: `!==` isn't an operator. You probably mean `!=`. But regardless, `op != "+" || op != "*" || op != "/" || op != "-"` isn't right either. No matter what value `op` is that statement will always be true. If `op` is "+", then `op != "*"`. If `op` is "*", then `op != "+"`, and so on.

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is. I _hope_ the first problem is that you get compilation errors. `printf("%.1f %s %.1f = %.1f", dNum1 , op ,dNum2, result);` would make your program have undefined behavior if it compiles.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't have operator `!==`, you should use `!=`.

As @largest-prime-is-463035818 pointed out, you also should use `&&`.

```
if(op != "+" && op != "*" && op != "/" && op != "-")
```

Comment: code is wrong also with `!=`. The condition needs `and` not `or`

Comment: Yup! it worked, Don't you know why the other sol. didn't work ?

Comment: @MohamedTarek Please see the linked duplicate target, which explains why in some detail.

Comment: @MohamedTarek Also, fix that `printf`. It can't handle a `std::string`

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, it doesn't output clearly and I cant solve it. could you suggest a fix?

Comment: @MohamedTarek I suggest using `std::cout << ...` instead, but if you must use `printf` you should use the argument `op.c_str()` instead `op`. Also, turn on more compiler warnings. That code would _usually_ generate errors or warnings.

Comment: printf() is a `c` function. It does not handle classes at all. `std::string` is a class. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/printf-with-stdstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865957/printf-with-stdstring)