# Getting a (const char*) representation of an integer in a one-liner

Tags: c++

I'm working on a software using a home-made report library which takes only (const char *) type as an argument :

```
ReportInfo(const char* information);
ReportError(const char* error);
[...]
```

As I'm trying to report value of integers, I'd like to get a representation of those integers in a `const char*` type. 
I can do it that way :

```
int value = 42;
string temp_value = to_string(value);
const char *final_value= temp_value.c_str();
ReportInfo(final_value);
```

It would be great if I could do it without instancing the *temp_value*.
I tried this :

```
int value = 42;
const char* final_value = to_string(value).c_str();
ReportInfo(final_value);
```

but `final_value` is equal to '\0' in that case.

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: I don't get the line "but final_value is egal to '\0' in that case."

Comment: Is there a shortage of newline characters in your work environment? Can you not spare the piddlingly small amount of memory needed for `temp_value`? :-)

Comment: Worth reading too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006891/stdstringc-str-and-temporaries

Comment: @DavidHaim When I debug this part of my code, i can see that the value in `final_value`is '\0'. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @augustin-r Because undefined behaviour doesn´t make sense. It´s a dangling pointer, nothing less or more.

Comment: @deviantfan ok. makes sense now. sry about that, i'm really new to programming :)

Comment: @augustin-r Nothing wrong with being new :)

Comment: @paxdiablo I have no memory issue here. I'm just curious :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
ReportInfo(to_string(value).c_str());
```

because the temporary will not be destroyed until `ReportInfo` returns.

Answer (score 4):

`to_string(value)` returns a temporary, so in your second example its lifetime ends at the end of the expression. so you have dangling pointer.