# Seemingly incorrect conversion from int to char* - how to see an issue

Tags: c++, memory, type-conversion, std, valgrind

To my understanding this code snippet has a problem, since `std::string` will be removed after `to_string` and `port` should have an incorrect value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int a = 123;
        const char* port = std::to_string(a).c_str();
        printf("val = %s", port);

        return 0;
}
```

However, program works just fine and prints "123" (with g++ compiler). Valgrind does not spot a problem as well.

Is there any way to demonstrate (maybe some tool or compiler option) that code above indeed has a problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006891/stdstringc-str-and-temporaries

Comment: Working fine (or at least *seemingly* working fine) is unfortunately one of the possibilities of UB.

Comment: That's why that conversion is explicit and has that **ugly** name `c_str()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not access after a free due to the small string optimization. If you change the code to `unsigned long long a = 1234567891343433ull;`, you will get complaints from `valgrind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot "detect" undefined behaviour, in general. Electric Fence *may* help.

You should catch these kinds of problems during peer review.

It is also possible to almost eradicate the risk of creating them, by avoiding `const char*` entirely.