# Arrays allocated at same address Cython + Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, cython

I came across some funny memory behavior working with numpy + cython, while trying to get data from a numpy array as a C array, to use in a GIL-free function. I've taken look at both the cython and numpy's array API but I haven't found any explanation. So consider the following lines of code:

```
cdef np.float32_t *a1 = <np.float32_t *>np.PyArray_DATA(np.empty(2, dtype="float32"))
print "{0:x}".format(<unsigned int>a1)
cdef np.float32_t *a2 = <np.float32_t *>np.PyArray_DATA(np.empty(2, dtype="float32"))
print "{0:x}".format(<unsigned int>a2)[]
```

I allocate two numpy arrays with numpy's empty function, and want to retrieve a pointer to the data buffer for each of them. You would expect these two pointers to point to two different memory addresses on the heap, possibly spaced by 2*4 bytes. But no, I get pointers to the same memory address, e.g.

```
>>>96a7aec0
>>>96a7aec0
```

How come? I managed to work around that by declaring my numpy arrays outside of the PyArray_DATA call, in such case, I get what I expect.

The only explanation I can think of, is that I don't create any Python object out of the scope of the PyArray_DATA function, and calling this function doesn't increment Python's reference count. Therefore the GC reclaims this memory space right after, and the next array is allocated at the now free previous memory address. Could somebody more cython-savvy than me could confirm that or give another explanation?

Comment: You create two temporary numpy arrays, they happen to be at the same address.

Comment: Why do you call them temporary numpy arrays? Does it relate to my explanation, that there are no python reference kept for them, hence they are "temporary".

Comment: Yes. They are garbage collected immediately. `a1` and `a2`  are also dangling pointers

Comment: OK thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create two temporary numpy arrays, they happen to be at the same address. Since no python references kept for them, they are garbage collected immediately, `a1` and `a2` also become dangling pointers.

If references kept for them, their addresses can not be the same, eg:

```
cdef int[:] a = np.arange(10)  # A memoryview will keep the numpy array from GC.
cdef int[:] b = np.arange(10)
cdef int* a_ptr = &a[0]
cdef int* b_ptr = &b[0]
print(<size_t>a_ptr)
print(<size_t>b_ptr)
```

---

**Grate care must be taken when using an object's underlying data. If used incorrectly, one often encounter a dangling pointer.** eg:

```
void cfunc(const char*)
# Fortunately, this won't compile in cython. 
# Error: Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference
cdef const char* = ("won't" + " compile").encode()
cfunc(char)
```

Right way:

```
# make sure keep_me is alive before cfunc have finished with it.
cdef bytes keep_me = ("right" + "way").encode() 
cfunc(temp)
# Or for single use.
cfunc(("right" + "way").encode())
```

---

Another example in c++ `std::string`'s member `c_str()`:

```
// The result of `+` will immediately destructed. cfunc got a  dangling pointer.
const char * s = (string("not") + string("good")).c_str();
cfunc(s);
```

Right way:

```
// keep `keep_me` for later use.
string keep_me = string("right") + string("way"); 
cfunc(keep_me.c_str());
// Or, for single use.
cfunc((string("right") + string("way")).c_str())
```

**Reference**: [std::string::c_str() and temporaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006891/stdstringc-str-and-temporaries)

Comment: Your c++ exemple is wrong. Your first call does not produce a dangling pointer as long as cfunc does not keep the pointer somewhere. What you probably wanted to write is: `const char* not_good = (string("not") + string("good")).c_str() // Produces a dangling pointer`