# C++ string conversion inside vs outside printf

Tags: c++, string, printf

I'm extracting text from a PDF using Poppler and used the following code to print the text:

```
for (std::vector<poppler::text_box>::iterator it = currpg.begin(); it != currpg.end(); ++it)
{
    const char *txt = it->text().to_latin1().c_str();
    printf("%s\n", txt);
}
```

It worked fine for all but one string: "Exemptions/Allowances:" which came out Ы`L/V.

I then tried the following code and the string printed properly:

```
for (std::vector<poppler::text_box>::iterator it = currpg.begin(); it != currpg.end(); ++it)
{
    std::string txt = it->text().to_latin1();
    printf("%s\n", txt.c_str());
}
```

For that one particular string, why does the conversion to c_str inside printf yield a different result than when conversion is done outside printf? I thought maybe the "/" was causing an issue but there were date strings that also had "/" and printed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer txt outlived a temporary variable.

```
it->text().to_latin1() // returns a temporary
const char *txt = it->text().to_latin1().c_str(); // stores the pointer to an internal buffer of the temporary
printf("%s\n", txt); // the temporary destroyed, the dangling pointer is used
```

The first example involves the undefined behaviour.

Your question is a duplicate. See [std::string::c_str() and temporaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006891/stdstringc-str-and-temporaries).

---

If you had used the C++ with its power, you would make shorter and safer code. Compare

```
std::string txt = it->text().to_latin1();
printf("%s\n", txt.c_str());
```

and

```
std::cout << it->text().to_latin1() << "\n";
```

Comment: FWIW `printf("%s\n", it->text().to_latin1().c_str());` would work as well.

Comment: @S.M. that makes perfect sense...thank you!

Comment: @dxiv I originally did it that way, but when I added 4 additional attributes to print from the text_box (not shown in post), the printf became unwieldy so used variables. Glad I did for educational purposes :)

Comment: Not sure if it's appropriate to ask follow-up in comments, but here goes: why doesn't the compiler recognize the unsafe assignment to a temporary and complain? Does the safety depend on how c_str() is executed and is unknown at compile time?